# find max value of a natural join table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: section and takes.
I made a natural join table to find how many people take a certain course. Which is:

```
 course_id | sec_id | semester | year | count 
-----------+--------+----------+------+-------
 CS-101    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 |     6
 CS-347    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 |     2
 PHY-101   | 1      | Fall     | 2009 |     1
```

Using this natural join table, I want to find the courses which have maximum number of students enrolled.

```
SELECT course_id, sec_id, semester, year, tb.count
FROM 
    (SELECT course_id, sec_id, semester, year, COUNT(*)
    FROM section
    NATURAL JOIN takes
    WHERE (semester, year) = ('Fall', 2009)
    GROUP BY course_id, sec_id, semester, year) AS tb
WHERE  
  tb.count = 
  (SELECT max(tb.count)
   FROM 
       (SELECT course_id, sec_id, semester, year, COUNT(*)
       FROM section
       NATURAL JOIN takes
       WHERE (semester, year) = ('Fall', 2009)
       GROUP BY course_id, sec_id, semester, year) AS tb
  ) ;
```

This is what I tried, and it works! Showing:

```
 course_id | sec_id | semester | year | count 
-----------+--------+----------+------+-------
 CS-101    | 1      | Fall     | 2009 |     6
```

But the code seems too redundant, so I thought maybe there is a simpler way to implement this. Is there a way to get the same answer without repeating the same joining process in the where clause all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=13cc30e79e79772f4684a169c4b9d686)

In your case you can use the `LIMIT` clause.

First order the max value to the top and then only give out the first record:

```
SELECT 
    <your query>
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

If you want to get ALL max values (e.g. if there are two records with `count = 6`) you could use the [`rank()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f19f93b04997a3c16cabbf3d93f91aa9)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        rank() OVER (ORDER BY count DESC) 
    FROM
        <your query>
) s
WHERE rank = 1
```

`rank()` adds an increasing value to each unique value (in that case to the `count` values). Tied values get the same rank value. The first one is always the `1`, so you are able to filter after that.

---

In some cases it could be better to go your original way, but extract your redundant code into a [CTE (`WITH` clause)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fe6d6e420ac1bce1979e012729799615) (for this small example without any joins and further subqueries the CTE seems to be a little bit faster; you could give it a try)

```
WITH cte AS (
    <your query>
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte
WHERE count = (SELECT max(count) FROM cte)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is great. But suppose If I want to get all rows that have the same max value, is there another way??

Comment: Added a solution for the extended problem

Comment: Added another idea